# A simple geometry question

Tags: geometry, inequality, triangles

[image]

Suppose $ABC$ is any triangle and $BE$ is any line from the vertex $B$ to a point $E$ lying inside the segment $AC$. Let $D$ be any point on $BE$. I would like to verify the following: regardless of how we have drawn the picture above, it is true that
$$
AB+BC\geq AD+DC.
$$
I tried playing around with triangle inequalities but nothing came out of that. Haven't done geometry in many years so not surprised that I blow. Could you please help? Thanks.

Comment: See http://prntscr.com/46y3tc

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The locus of the points $P$ of the plane such that $AP+PC=AB+BC$ is the ellipse $\Gamma$ through $B$ with foci in $A$ and $C$. Since such ellipse is convex, for any point $Q$ inside $\Gamma$ we have $AQ+QC < AB+BC$.

Answer (score 1):

Why not decompose direct connections in a vector notational way:
$$
AB = AE + EB
$$
Then it's simple to say
$$
AB + BC = AE + EB + BE + EC
\\
AD + DC = AE + ED + DE + EC
$$
And now use $AB = BA$ for all $A, B$, so in the end
$$
AB + BC \geq AD + BC
\\
\Leftrightarrow EB \geq ED
$$
which is certainly true by construction.

Comment: You're mixing scalars and vectors. Making me a bit unease.

Comment: Yes, that's true. $XY$ in vector speech would look like $\vec y - \vec x$, while in scalar *context* it's $\| \vec y - \vec x \|$. Actually I was not familiar with that notation $XY$, so that may have lead to confusion.